# How to implement IEnumerator for map coordinates?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I find myself using the following pattern a lot when enumerating through all tile positions on a map:

```
for (int y = (int) map.Rect.y; y < map.Rect.yMax; y++)
    {
        for (int x = (int) map.Rect.x; x < map.Rect.xMax; x++)
        {
            // do something with X and Y coordinates
        }
    }
```

I've been studying IEnumerator and IEnumerable but I can't figure out how to implement them to the Map.

What I'd like to achieve:

```
foreach (Vector3Int position in Map)
    {
        DoSomething(position.x, position.y);
    }
```

And then Map can internally handle the rest of the logic, with this simpler syntax.

Comment: Something like this? `for (int y = (int) map.Rect.y; y < map.Rect.yMax; y++) for (int x = (int) map.Rect.x; x < map.Rect.xMax; x++) yield return newPosition(x, y);`

Comment: What kind of map and what kind of position?

Comment: I'm looking for the entire syntax of the code, I have no idea how to implement an IEnumerator. Does my map class have to inherit it? Or does there just have to be a function called Enumerate which returns an IEnumerator. Any details help.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's a coordinate grid for a game I'm developing.

Comment: @jamlovpristin: well, you should include the types used, it's also not helping to hide them with `var`.

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-5.0) is usually a good place to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) them:

```
public IEnumerable<Point> AllMapPoints()
{
    for (int y = (int) map.Rect.y; y < map.Rect.yMax; y++)
    {
        for (int x = (int) map.Rect.x; x < map.Rect.xMax; x++)
        {
            yield return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can loop them all:

```
foreach (var point in AllMapPoints())
{
    DoSomething(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

or just some, for example:

```
foreach (var point in AllMapPoints().Take(100))
{
    DoSomething(point.X, point.Y);
}
```